# Transferring in Copenhagen

Tags: transit, luggage, airport-security, cph

This January I'm headed to Italy to study, and I will be transferring through Copenhagen. I wasn't thinking when I booked my tickets about having to potentially recheck luggage at the airport. Now I'm worried that I won't have enough time as IcelandAir and AlItalia don't have any agreements in place. My layover is an hour and 20 minutes long; will it be possible to go through security and recheck my bag in this short time? Or will I have to rebook?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: What citizenship are you?

Comment: Is it all on one ticket, or is it two tickets?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to recheck luggage (if you have a single ticket, check with Icelandair before you do anything rash!) it will be cutting it rather close.

It will probably take at least 20 minutes until your bag is on the carousel, longer than that in busy periods. The baggage reclaim is in Terminal 3 for all international arrivals, and you then have to carry the bag to Terminal 2 (assume 10 minutes for this) to recheck it on Alitalia.

If you get the bag checked in time to get it on the flight, going through security yourself and onwards to the gate will probably not be the critical factor.

All in all it's probably doable on a good (or even average) day, but it won't take many random complications to make you miss the onward flight.